# Creating natural environments that can run on lower end computers in Unity3D/C#

Tags: c#, unity

So, I'm starting work on a project soon that will require me to create realistic environments that can preferably run on PC's besides high quality ones. The goal is to get as real an environment as possible while still being easy(ish) to run.

The only problem is I've NEVER done anything with 3D environments, making trees sway, grass move, lighting, etc. Can anyone give me any help? Perhaps describe how it's done? Link me to articles? I'm just looking to be pointed in the right direction, not for you to write the code for me.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, I'm using Unity3D and C# as my language.

Thanks,

Tim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 3D environments

You can sculpt the basic ground terrain with Unity's Terrain tool, but beyond that you need to model complex objects in a 3D modelling program, then import them into Unity and place them within a scene. How to do 3D modelling is beyond the scope of a question like this. Alternatively you can sometimes buy the models pre-made from the Unity Asset Store.

> making trees sway, grass move

Unity can do this for you, if you place trees and grass with the Unity terrain editor. There are various parameters to let you specify how much you want things to sway. This requires you to place 'wind zones' in the level.

> lighting

Lighting is as complex or as difficult as you want. To get started you can make sure all objects have shadows turned on, then add one directional light for the sun (make it yellowy-white) and then add an ambient light to lighten the shadows. It won't win any prizes but it's a reasonable starting point. More realistic lighting can use a variety of different tricks, such as multiple directional lights, lightmaps, ambient occlusion, more complex shaders, etc etc - which to use and how would be a question in itself.

Comment: As for the models, there's a 3D artist working on this project that will do any models we need. - 

If I had the 3D modeler create the trees in a modelling program, and imported trees in to the game, could I still affect them with wind zones and such? - 

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction for light, I'll probably look up more on how to get a realistic lighting environment.

Comment: No, you need to create the trees in such a way that they're compatible with the Unity tree engine - because they're effectively animated objects.

Comment: Hmm, so is there any way at all to create trees with an external program that would be compatible with the Unity tree engine? Can you actually use Unity as a 3D modeling program and create trees with it? Or are all the trees pre-made assets?

Comment: I believe you have to use the tree creator, which is not exactly a 3D modelling program but which lets you define a tree's properties. http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/class-Tree.html

Comment: I read up on it, the tree creator should be usable. And by Unity's Terrain tool you meant the Terrain Toolkit, right?

Comment: No, I just meant the inbuilt Terrain object and the tools that work on it, but you can add the toolkit if you like.

Comment: Alright, thank you SO much for all the help. I know exactly where to go now and what to do. You were great help. One final question for the artist, if you want to could you build the terrain itself in an outside 3D Modelling program and import it in to Unity? Or does Unity need you to create the terrain in there for certain things?

Comment: Terrain has to be made in Unity. You can make a model in another package that looks like terrain, but it doesn't offer the same features, such as tree and grass placement.

Comment: Alright, thanks a ton for all your help. The artist wanted me to ask you a question, for buildings (like if a whole level is inside a building,) do you need to create that in Unity? Or if you were making a dungeon or something could you make it outside and then import it in? Or does Unity need EVERY level to be made in it for lighting/sound/etc?

Comment: Unity isn't a modelling app; you make models outside and import them. The only thing you shape in Unity is terrain, ie. outdoor areas.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. So terrain and trees need to be made inside, but buildings, rocks, and other objects can be made outside and imported in. Thanks a ton for all your help, you've definitely made this a lot easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest performance balance tricks is to limit the visible distance of older machines with fog and use of billboards.  If you have a high end PC you can have all the trees be actual 3d objects, but by having a check in your software, such as which shader level is available, on an older machine that is using an older shader API, you can set your engine to that the trees closest to the player(of the older PC) are 3D, the trees in a mid-range area are billboards (two images of the same tree configured in a perpendicular pattern "a cross", to give the illusion of a 3D tree using 2 static images), and the trees in the background could be incorporated into your sky-box texture.  Then start using the fog effect on your mid-range billboard trees.  It will give the appearance of the engine the high end PC will see but reduce the shadow and light calculation processing that would bog down an older machine. As for movement in trees and grass, remember that those conditions should only occur within the player's line of sight (if the player can't see it - your not required to display or calculate it.)

Comment: Hmmm, thanks, I'll talk about this with the dev. This could be a useful trick to get it to run on a lot more PC's.